# How to use Android DataStore with multi users or files

Tags: android, android-jetpack, koin, coroutinescope, android-jetpack-datastore

I want to store some preferences using DataStore. But the problem is that my application can have multiple users and therefor needs to store these preferences in separate files. I got a working example using only one user but I'm struggling to support multiple users.

Here is an example of my code:

```
class DataStorageRepository(private val context: Context, private val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val SETTING_ONE = intPreferencesKey("setting_one")
    }

    // retrieve datastore for currently logged in user. 
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = userRepository.currentRegistration().name)

    val userPreferencesFlow: Flow<UserPreferences> = context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        val settingOne = preferences[PreferencesKeys.SETTING_ONE] ?: 0

        UserPreferences(settingOne)
    }

    suspend fun storeSettingOne(settingOne: Int) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.SETTING_ONE] = settingOne
        }
    }

    data class UserPreferences(val lastUsedToAccountTab: Int)
}
```

I'm using `Koin` and I tried unloading the `DataStorageRepository` on logout and recreating it on login but the DataStore seems to stay alive until the app is killed and I get the following crash:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active
> for the same file: [...] You should either maintain your DataStore as
> a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the
> same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).

I also tried to use a `CoroutineScope` and kill that when I log out, but after recreating the scope on login the DataStore doesn't seem to get recreated.

Does DataStore support a way to close the connection or to handle multiple files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment I was posting this question I found a solution to this problem. In order to solve my problem I needed to combine my previous two solutions. So on logout I unload the `DataStorageRepository` and on login I reload it again. I also needed to create a `CoroutineScope` that I cancel on logout.

**My Module**

```
val loggedInModule = module {
    single { DataStorageRepository(get(), get()) }
}
```

**I created a scope and passed it to the DataStore**

```
var loggedInScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = userRepository.currentRegistration().name, scope = loggedInScope)
```

**On Login**

```
loggedInScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
loadKoinModules(loggedInModule)
```

**On Logout**

```
loggedInScope.cancel()
unloadKoinModules(loggedInModule)
```

Answer (score 15):

**Put this line inside companion object { }**

```
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settingPrefs")
```

**My Code**

```
class SettingPrefs(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settingPrefs")
        private val soundKey = booleanPreferencesKey("sound")
        private val vibrateKey = booleanPreferencesKey("vibrate")
    }

    val getSound: Flow<Boolean>
        get() = context.dataStore.data.map {
            it[soundKey] ?: true
        }

    suspend fun setSound(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { it[soundKey] = value }
    }

    val getVibration: Flow<Boolean>
        get() = context.dataStore.data.map {
            it[vibrateKey] ?: true
        }

    suspend fun setVibration(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { it[vibrateKey] = value }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use different key for different user or manual keep DataStore  **singleton**.

---

**For exception:**

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: [...] You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).**

`androidx.datastore:datastore-*:1.0.0-alpha07` is released.

Put this at the **top level** of your kotlin file so there is only one instance of it.

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

class Xxx{

}
```

> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore#1.0.0-alpha07.
>
> The Context.createDataStore extension function has been removed and replaced with globalDataStore property delegate. Call globalDataStore once at the top level in your kotlin file. For example:
>
> ```
> val Context.myDataStore by dataStore(...)
> ```
>
> Put this at the top level of your kotlin file so there is only one instance of it. (I57215, b/173726702)

Answer (score 5):

Just put your declaration datastore out of your DataStorageRepository class

```
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name="settings")

class DataStorageRepository(context: Context) {

   private var appContext = context.applicationContext

   val mData: Flow<String?> = appContext.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
          preferences[YOUR_KEY]
   }

   suspend fun insertData(value: String) {
        appContext.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
             preferences[YOUR_KEY] = authToken
        }
   }

   companion object {
        private val KEY = stringPreferencesKey("data")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way, you use `PreferenceDataStoreFactory`:

```
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferenceDataStoreFactory

fun createUserDataStore(email: String): DataStore<Preferences> {
    return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create {
        applicationContext.preferencesDataStoreFile("user_settings_$email")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using in my project:

```kotlin
private object UserIdBasedPrefDs {

  val lock = Any()

  @GuardedBy("lock")
  @Volatile
  var currentId: String = ""

  @GuardedBy("lock")
  @Volatile
  var INSTANCE: DataStore<Preferences>? = null
}

fun Context.happyStore( // rename what ever you like.
  userId: String,
  // below 3 optional params are same as int the `preferencesDataStore`.
  corruptionHandler: ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler<Preferences>? = null,
  produceMigrations: (Context) -> List<DataMigration<Preferences>> =
    { listOf() },
  scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

): DataStore<Preferences> = UserIdBasedPrefDs.run {

  // check if current user id has been changed.
  if (userId != currentId && INSTANCE != null) {
    synchronized(lock) {
      // release previous saved.
      INSTANCE = null
      // reset new user id.
      currentId = userId
    }
  }

  // below is the same logic inside the `preferencesDataStore` delegate.
  INSTANCE ?: synchronized(lock) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
      INSTANCE = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        corruptionHandler = corruptionHandler,
        migrations = produceMigrations(applicationContext),
        scope = scope
      ) {
        applicationContext.preferencesDataStoreFile(userId)
      }
    }
    INSTANCE!!
  }
}
```

Hope it can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataStorageRepository` can't be always alive in the whole application. When user changed, the repository instance should be changed too. Meanwhile，the file name of DataStore should be changed based on the User info.